# Getting the Rows from DataTable1 where they are not in DataTable2

Tags: asp.net, linq, datatable

I have 2 datatable

```
DataTable1
SNo
1
2
3
4

DataTable2

SNo
1
4
3

I want the result

DataTableResult

SNo
2
```

I can do it using `for` loop.

But I am trying to do it using linq.

```
var intersection = DataTable1.AsEnumerable().Intersect(DataTable2.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);
```

Then I found out Intersect is will give u the rows where both tables have.

I dunno exactly what function to use.

Any ideas?

I have got the answer.

Thanks to the person who deleted the answer.

But that gives me a start.

The answer is

```
var intersection = DataTable1.AsEnumerable().Except(DataTable2.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try using exept statement it aliitle hard to be precise since you only show the table as structure but you can try somethink like this

```
 var qry1 = datatable1.AsEnumerable().Select(a => new { SNo.ToString() });
 var qry2 = datatable2.AsEnumerable().Select(b => new { SNo.ToString() });
 var exceptAB = qry1.Except(qry2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like this

```
select SNo from DataTable1 where SNo not in (select SNo from DataTable2);
```